# Как работает php

Tags: php

На хабре нашел вот такую информацию:

> Вначале, написанный нами код разбирается лексическим анализатором.
>   Далее, полученные лексемы, передаются в синтаксический анализатор.
>   Если синтаксический анализатор дал добро, то лексемы передаются
>   транслятору, а он, в свою очередь, генерирует так называемые opcodes
>   (operation codes). И только после этого, в дело вступает виртуальная
>   машина PHP (та самая Zend Engine) которая и выполняет наш алгоритм из
>   получившихся opcodes. Opcodes так же называют эдаким php-шным
>   ассемблером.

Но также известно что php интерпретируемый язык.

**Вопрос** : вышеописанный метод исполняется построчно или сначала выполняется поэтапно(ожидая когда анализатор полностю проверит код) а потом уже 'опкод' выполняет построчно

Comment: ну дак у вас же не генерируется исполняемый файл, который вы потом можете запускать всегда, поэтому и интерпретируемый. Такая процедура проводится при каждом обращении к файлу, каждый раз он разбирается и интепретируется. Покуда вы не включите расширения сервера для кэширования опкода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю PHP по классификации является чем-то средним между интерпретируемые и компилируемым языком. Основное различие между этими классами в том что в компилируемых языках весь текст программы переводиться в машинный код программами, которые называются трансляторами (компиляторами), только после создания исполняемого файла, алгоритм запускается в работу. В интерпретируемых же языках, программа под названием интерпретатор проходит отдельно по каждой строчке кода и отдельно их выполняет. Преимущества этого над компилируемыми языками в том что можно контролировать программу на любом ее этапе, большой же недостаток в быстродействии, т к машинный код исполняется процессором намного быстрее, и так же в завершении исполнения при первой же ошибке. Так вот в движке PHP присутствует и программа транслятор и программа интерпретатор. В целях быстродействия сначала текст программы переводиться в байт-код, но при этом исполнительный файл не создаётся, и потом уже этот байт-код интерпретируется "построчно". 
Таким образом выходит некий гибрид, где сначала программа транслируется (компилируется) в более быстрый байт-код, а потом эта же программа, только уже представленная байт-кодом интерпретируется и исполняется. Также это движок PHP называют интерпретатором со встроенным блоком трансляции, который оптимизирует код той самой интерпретации.

Как-то так. Надеюсь Вам это поможет!

Comment: Еще интересует Zend Engine. Это же виртуальная машина которая исполняет промежуточный код. Виртуальную машину используют только ради кроссплатформенности?

Comment: Да, вы правы, как раз zend и занимается трансляцией и интерпретацией кода. Я думаю что используют её скорее для повышения быстродействия и производительности, но могу ошибаться. Собственно это и было первоначальной задачей при разработке zend engine.